# How to ignore JobCancellationException?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

Recently, I've upgraded Kotlin Coroutines from experimental to 1.1.1 and faced the problem that `job.cancel()` in new version works differently.

Here's the code with Experimental Coroutines:

```
fun <R : Any, T : Deferred<R>> T.runAsync(
        job: Job,
        onSuccess: (result: R) -> Unit,
        onFailed: (errorMsg: String?) -> Unit) {
    launch(UI, parent = job) {
        try {
            val result = this@runAsync.await()
            onSuccess(result)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            onFailed(e.message)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's with 1.1.1:

```
fun <R : Any, T : Deferred<R>> T.runAsync(
        job: Job,
        onSuccess: (result: R) -> Unit,
        onFailed: (errorMsg: String?) -> Unit) {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main + job) {
        try {
            val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                this@runAsync.await()
            }
            onSuccess(result)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            onFailed(e.message)
        }
    }
}
```

For example:

My fragment destroyed and called `job.cancel()` during coroutine is running.

In experimental coroutines neither `onSuccess()` nor `onFailed()` will be called.

In 1.1.1: `onFailed()` called because caught of `JobCancellationException`

I figured out to add `catch (e: JobCancellationException)`, but it's impossible:

```
/**
 * @suppress **This an internal API and should not be used from general code.**
 */
internal expect class JobCancellationException(
```

So, the question is: How to handle/ignore `JobCancellationException` ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You try to catch the super-class `CancellationException` instead, which is a part of the public API.

Do note that if something throws `CancellationException` you are generally expected to rethrow it so upstream objects are notified about the cancellation. See [Cancellation is Cooperative](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative)